# Does Parse Server support basic authentication via link params?

Tags: curl, heroku, https, basic-authentication, parse-server

I have a Parse Server installed on Heroku with Parse Cloud code that I can verify is handling POSTs via "curl" commands, but am getting authorization errors via "basic HTTP authentication".  Does anyone know if ParserServer has implemented basic HTTP authentication?

If they have, would you be able to tell me how to transform the following "curl" command (that works) into one that uses basic HTTP authentication?

This works (I have taken out the -d data clause for clarity):

```
curl -X POST -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: <key>" \
             -H "X-Parse-Master-Key: *KEY*" \
             -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: *KEY*" \
             -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
             https://*SERVER*.herokuapp.com/parse/functions/bloodPressureMonitorData
```

this URL w/basic authentication does not:

```
https://*KEY*:javascript-key:*KEY*@*SERVER*.herokuapp.com/parse/functions/bloodPressureMonitorData
```

Maybe I need the "master key" too?  But I don't know the syntax for that...